# Understanding JavaScript scopes

Tags: javascript, scopes

I'm trying to understand how scopes work in JS. Can you tell me if I correct with understanding of this chunk of code:

```
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
 setTimeout(function timeoutHandler() {
   var i = i;
   console.log(i); //undefined
 })
}
```

`console.log` prints `undefined` 5 times. So as I understand, when `timeoutHandler` is executed, it has its own local scope with own `i` variable. So is that correct that during `timeoutHandler` execution, the interpreter asks for `i` variable, finds it declared in local scope and uses this declared variable for assignment? This explains why it is `undefined`, but I'm not sure I'm fully correct.
Thanks

**UPD**
I don't need this code to work properly, I just want to understand why it behaves like that in this case

Comment: `var i = i` inside the setTimeout callback handler creates a new scope for `i` and `i` hasn't been defined yet before assigning it to `i` again. Hence `i` is `undefined`.

Comment: Firstly `var i = i` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `var i = i` is equivalent to `var i; i = i;`.

Comment: Try passing in the `i` as a param of the `setTimeout`

Comment: @JJJ which would explain why `i` gets set to `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for responses. Just to make clear I don't use this code anywhere and don't need it to work properly. I just wanted to understand why it behaves like that it this case.

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous. It gets set five times in the loop, but isn't fired until the end of the loop. While the function inside it has it's own scope with it's own `i`. That's the reason this will print `undefined`. If `var i = i` would be left out, console would print `5` since that is the final result of the loop before `setTimeout` fires.

Comment: As @Mouser said, i ends up being set to 5 for each setTimeout callback. Maybe you're already familiar with this, but your code might behave more intuitively if you used `let` instead of `var`. let uses block scoping, and the numbers will iterate in the setTimeout function the way you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make sense of it by this example:

```js
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
//create a self executing function 
 (function(iValue){
  //in this scope iValue has the i from the loop
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(iValue); //will print the correct i
 })
 })(i); //pass i in it's current context to the function
}
```

Or easier with ES6:
Use `let` instead of `var`.
Since `let` is scoped within the block (each run of the loop is it's own block) it will not get another value inside the `setTimeout`.

```js
for(let i = 0; i<5; i++){
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(i); //will print the correct i
 })
}
```